# Calculator with GUI + and * doesn't work

Tags: powershell

I'm making a calculator with a GUI in powershell as an training.
I've copy/pasted the calculator from an other script and there id worked properly.
On the new script the -, /, ^, √ work but +, * does not work.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")

[void] 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$objFormfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objFormfenster1.Backcolor="white"
$objFormfenster1.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objFormfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(500,500)
$objFormfenster1.Text = "Calculator with GUI"

$objLabelfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabelfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,30)
$objLabelfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,40)
$objLabelfenster1.Text = "Geben Sie die erste Zahl ein (wenn Sie keine zahl eingeben wird automatisch 0 genommen):"
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objLabelfenster1)

$objTextBoxfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBoxfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,70)
$objTextBoxfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)
$objTextBoxfenster1.Text
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objTextBoxfenster1)

$objLabelfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabelfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,110)
$objLabelfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,40)
$objLabelfenster1.Text = "Wählen Sie den Operator aus (bei Wurzel nur im ersten Feld zahl eingeben):"
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objLabelfenster1)

$objComboboxfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
$objComboboxfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,150)
$objComboboxfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)
$objComboboxfenster1.Height = 70
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objComboboxfenster1)
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("+")
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("-")
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("*")
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("/")
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("^")
[void] $objComboboxfenster1.Items.Add("√")
$objComboboxfenster1.SelectedItem
$objComboboxfenster1.Add_SelectedIndexChanged({ })

$objLabelfenster2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabelfenster2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,190)
$objLabelfenster2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,40)
$objLabelfenster2.Text = "Geben Sie die zweite Zahl ein (wenn Sie keine zahl eingeben wird automatisch 0 genommen):"
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objLabelfenster2)

$objTextBoxfenster2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$objTextBoxfenster2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,230)
$objTextBoxfenster2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,30)
$objTextBoxfenster2.Text
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($objTextBoxfenster2)

$GoButtonfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$GoButtonfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120,405)
$GoButtonfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$GoButtonfenster1.Text = "Go"
$GoButtonfenster1.Name = "Go"
$GoButtonfenster1.DialogResult = "None"
$GoButtonfenster1.Add_Click({
  $zahl1 = $null
  $zahl2 = $null
  $operator = $null
  [string]$zahl1 = $objTextBoxfenster1.Text
  [string]$zahl2 = $objTextBoxfenster2.Text
  $operator = $objComboboxfenster1.SelectedItem
  $iserror = "False"

  $zahl1 = $zahl1 -as [int]
   if($zahl1 -like $null) {
     $iserror = "True"
     $result = $null
   }  

  $zahl2 = $zahl2 -as [int]
   if($zahl2 -like $null) {
     $iserror = "True"
     $result = $null
  }

  if ($iserror -eq "True"){
     [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Error: Eine Zahl wurde falsch eingegeben","Error") 
  }

    switch ($operator) {
        "+" {$result = $zahl1 + $zahl2}
        "-" {$result = $zahl1 - $zahl2}
        "*" {$result = $zahl1 * $zahl2}
        "/" {$result = $zahl1 / $zahl2}
        "^" {$result = [math]::pow( $zahl1, $zahl2 )}
        "√" {$result = [math]::sqrt( $zahl1 ) }
    default {$iserror = "True"}  
}

  if ($iserror -eq "False"){
     [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$result","Das Ergebniss") 
  }
})
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($GoButtonfenster1)

$CancelButtonfenster1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButtonfenster1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30,405)
$CancelButtonfenster1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$CancelButtonfenster1.Text = "Exit"
$CancelButtonfenster1.Name = "Exit"
$CancelButtonfenster1.DialogResult = "Cancel"
$CancelButtonfenster1.Add_Click({$objFormfenster1.Close()})
$objFormfenster1.Controls.Add($CancelButtonfenster1)

[void] $objFormfenster1.ShowDialog()
```

Scriptinputtranslation (German -> Englisch)

If you run the script it first asks you for the first number, then for the operator and then for the second number. If you put letters or other characters in the number fields, there will be an error telling you, that you have put a wrong character in one of the fields. If you type in numbers and a select an operator a windows will pop up and tell you the result.

Comment: _Scriptinputtranslation (German -> Englisch)_ What do you mean? P.S.: `Ergebniss` ist weder Englisch noch (gutes) Deutsch ;)

Comment: `if($zahl2 -like $null) {` Keep in mind, empty String and null valued Variables are evaluated to `$false`. So you can simply use `if ($zahl2) {"We have a value"} else {"Error, no value"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem starts here:

> ```
> [string]$zahl1 = $objTextBoxfenster1.Text
> [string]$zahl2 = $objTextBoxfenster2.Text
> ```

At this point you have strongly typed `$zahl1` and `$zahl2`. What happens now is that every assignment to those variables is *automatically converted to string*. You can confirm this be the presense of the variable attribute `System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute`

```
[string]$var = "5"
Get-Variable var | ft *
```

So even though you try to type them as `[int]`'s in later code they are still strings.

```
[string]$var = "5"
write-host "`$var: $var is $($var.GetType().Fullname)"
$var = $var -as [int]
write-host "`$var: $var is $($var.GetType().Fullname)"
```

**Output**

```
$var: 5 is System.String
$var: 5 is System.String
```

So if I remove the variable and the strong type declaration I get the results you were likely expecting.

```
remove-variable var
$var = "5"
write-host "`$var: $var is $($var.GetType().Fullname)"
$var = $var -as [int]
write-host "`$var: $var is $($var.GetType().Fullname)"
```

**Output**

```
$var: 5 is System.String
$var: 5 is System.Int32
```

You could probably just simplify some of your logic as such

```
$zahl1 = $objTextBoxfenster1.Text -as [int]
$zahl2 = $objTextBoxfenster2.Text -as [int]

if($zahl1 -and $zahl2){
    # Do your switch based math now
} else {
    # something is wrong with one of them
    Write-Warning "try again.... with real numbers this time."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to multiply string by string, if you do simple test in the console:

```
"2" * 2"
```

you will get 22 and not 4

```
2 * 2
```

The results will be correct: 4

So just cast your results to $zahl1/$zahl2 variables to int type and you will get right results:

So, change this section (I just modified the '*' and '+', you change the rest):

```
switch ($operator) {
        "+" {$result = [int]$zahl1 + [int]$zahl2}
        "-" {$result = $zahl1 - $zahl2}
        "*" {$result = [int]$zahl1 * [int]$zahl2}
        "/" {$result = $zahl1 / $zahl2}
        "^" {$result = [math]::pow( $zahl1, $zahl2 )}
        "√" {$result = [math]::sqrt( $zahl1 ) }
    default {$iserror = "True"}
```

or change this section:

```
[int]$zahl1 = $objTextBoxfenster1.Text
[int]$zahl2 = $objTextBoxfenster2.Text
```

Comment: he needs to change just the switch part, I tested it before and after and it's ok

Comment: that last edit is bad advice as that will cause an error if the text is not capable of casting to [int]. Have a look at my answer that explains what is happening and a couple of approaches to fixing it.